# where did netmemorycache.ini go?

Tags: .net, performance

I am trying to set up perf counters for .net MemoryCache and found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059000/where-are-net-4-0-memorycache-performance-counters/20059960#20059960) that looked promising.  But it assumes that there is an aspnet_perf.ini file in the Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 directory.  But I don't see that file on my machine (I do see the directory).  Do I have to install something else to get this file?