# Writable Performance Counter doesn't throw exception

Tags: .net, performancecounter

Using .NET 4.7, reference source [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/PerformanceCounter.cs). According to the docs, the constructor `public PerformanceCounter (string categoryName, string counterName, string instanceName, bool readOnly);` should throw an InvalidOperationException if the counterName doesn't exist.

But as you can see from the source, it only does this check if the counter is read-only. For example, this returns just fine:

```
new PerformanceCounter("ExistingCategory","NameDefinitelyDoesntExist", "ExistingInstance, false)`
```

So, will I run into a runtime exception later on? I am otherwise assuming that as long as the counter is writable and the category name exists, the corresponding performance counter doesn't need to actually exist on the local machine.

I want to do this just so I can write some code using the performance counter that will run on a lot of machines without going through the drudgery of making sure the counter exists on every machine.

Comment: The bigger idea behind this is that a missing performance counter is quite normal.  [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059960/17034), lots of .NET framework counters need to be installed first with the lodctr.exe utility.  Writing such a counter is not a problem, nothing happens.  No extra code required, easy peasy.  Reading is a problem, now you can no longer ignore that it is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, methinks you can always read from a writable PerformanceCounter, so the difference in behavior is odd. The docs are certainly incorrect here.

It looks .NET is trying to antipicate your whim, as an InvalidOperationException [*will* be thrown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) when `NextValue()`, the method for reading from a performance counter, is called, whether or not it is read-only. For a read-only performance counter, this is one of the only methods you would wish to invoke, and .NET will simply throw the exception sooner rather than later.

Furthermore it appears that **writing** to the performance counter (via `RawValue`, `IncrementBy`, `Decrement`, etc.) will succeed whether or not the corresponding Windows counter actually exists, as our celebrity guest Hans Passant has suggested.